# Is Declaration of Variable in C Limited to Extern Keyword Alone Vs Definition

Tags: c

I had a doubt that there is something i am missing seeking for the difference between Declaration and Definition and i found the link
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/commonly-asked-c-programming-interview-questions-set-1/
Its stated here that

```
// This is only declaration. y is not allocated memory by this statement 
  extern int y; 

  // This is both declaration and definition, memory to x is allocated by this statement.
  int x;
```

Now if I go by the below piece of code

```
int main() 
{ 
{ 
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20; 
    { 
        // The outer block contains declaration of x and y, so 
        // following statement is valid and prints 10 and 20 
        printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y); 
        { 
            // y is declared again, so outer block y is not accessible 
            // in this block 
            int y = 40; 

            x++; // Changes the outer block variable x to 11 
            y++; // Changes this block's variable y to 41 

            printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y); 
        } 

        // This statement accesses only outer block's variables 
        printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y); 
    } 
} 
return 0; 
}
```

**I will get the below result**

```
x = 10, y = 20
x = 11, y = 41
x = 11, y = 20
```

If i modify just the **int y = 40** in the innermost block to **y = 40**
then the code will look like

//int y;

```
int main() 
{ 
{ 
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20; 
    { 
        // The outer block contains declaration of x and y, so 
        // following statement is valid and prints 10 and 20 
        printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y); 
        { 
            // y is declared again, so outer block y is not accessible 
            // in this block 
            y = 40; 

            x++; // Changes the outer block variable x to 11 
            y++; // Changes this block's variable y to 41 

            printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y); 
        } 

        // This statement accesses only outer block's variables 
        printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y); 
    }
} 
return 0; 
}
```

and the result will be

```
x = 10, y = 20
x = 11, y = 41
x = 11, y = 41
```

My friend told me this is because we are declaring a new **y** which is local to the block in the first code and that is not in the second case , i didn't get why as we are only writing the data type in front of the variable a second time , does this mean by writing data type we reserved a new memory space and created a new variable , please explain .

If i go by another article on Stackoverflow on the Link
[What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

i see that whenever we say that we are Declaring a Variable, the variable is preceded by the extern keyword and i am speaking strictly related to C and not any other language.

So can we generalize to Declaration of variable as preceded by extern Keyword.

I understand my English might be bad and difficult for you to understand , please bear with me.

Comment: Reading C++ answers isn't that helpful if you're learning C.

Answer (score 2):

```
    { 
        // y is declared again, so outer block y is not accessible 
        // in this block 
        y = 40;
```

Your comment is wrong.  This is not *declaring* `y` again. It's simply assigning to it.

It should instead say:

```
// This changes the value of y in the outer block
```

> does this mean by writing data type we reserved a new memory space and created a new variable

Yes.

- `int y` is a declaration of a new variable.
- `int y = 40` is a declaration *and* initialization.
- `y = 40` is an assignment to an *existing* variable.

Comment: Why i am getting different result in both the codes int y = 40 , is also like assigning a new value to variable y again.

Comment: Like I said, you're simply assigning to `y`; you're just changing its value. There's no new variable. That's why you see the change in the outer `printf`.

Comment: If int y is just a declaration then why as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration int y; is a definition and not declaration

Comment: It would be better to use word *definition* rather than *declaration* when speaking of local variables. It's impossible *declare* local variable without also *defining* it.

Answer (score 1):

`extern int y;` tells the compiler that `y` may be declared in another file that is linked to this program, be it library, header file, et cetera, and that if the compiler finds that global variable called `y`, then it should use its memory address for the `y` declared in this file.  I.e.:

```
//Look for a global variable called "y" in the included files
//If it is found, use its memory address
extern int y;
```

**Now, for your first code example...**

First, you declare and instantiate two variables, `x` and `y`.

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;
```

Then you print them, resulting in `x = 10, y = 20` being printed.  This makes sense, since `x` is 10 and `y` is 20.

Then, you create a new scope using curly brackets and declare a new variable called `y`.  Since this variable has the same name as a variable in a scope higher than it, it **hides the outer variable called** `y` until this scope is exited.

```
{
    int y = 40;
```

Any changes to *this* `y` will not affect the outer `y`, and the outer `y` cannot be accessed until the scope of *this* `y` has been exited.

Then you increment `x` and `y`, and then print the result.  `x = 11, y = 41` is printed due to the above behaviour.

After printing the above string, the code exits the current scope.  Because of this, the outer `y` is no longer hidden, and it can now be accessed.

Finally, you print `x` and `y` again.  `x` is 11 because it was incremented earlier, but the outer `y` *was not incremented*, thus `x = 11, y = 20` is printed.

---

Replacing `int y = 40` with `y = 40` like you did in your second code example results in only one `y` variable being declared and instantiated.  Therefore, `y` ends up being 41 at the third `printf()` statement.

Comment: Very Thanks Tau for the nice explanation..
have one more scenario , what if i declare and initializes int y = 5 
outside the main , it will be like a global then

Comment: `
    int y=5;
    int main() 
    { 
    { 
        int x = 10;
        int y = 20; 
        { 
            printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y); 
            { 
                int y;  
                x++; 
                y++;    
                printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y); 
            } 
            printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y); 
        } 
    } 
    return 0; 
    } 
`    
I am getting the below result
`    
    x = 10, y = 20
    x = 11, y = 32765
    **x** = 11, y = 20
`

Comment: @beastboy make sure to give the inner `y` a value before you use it.  otherwise, you'll get **Undefined Behaviour** since the inner `y` will have garbage data in it before you use it.

Comment: and yes, if you declare and instantiate `y` outside of `main()`, then it will be global.